# Open xz file from the command line in Windows 10

Tags: cmd, windows-10, xz

My colleagues using mac or linux open xz files with this line:

```
xz --decompress --stdout "file.csv.xz"
```

On my pc, with windows 10, I get the following error:

> 'xz' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Is the command different on windows?
Or is it a matter of installing a program and putting it in the right directory (like you need curl.exe to use rcurl for example)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you need to install `xz` on the computer in order to run it. http://tukaani.org/xz/

7-Zip has supported .xz files for some time and you might be able to use that if it is already installed. http://www.7-zip.org/

Comment: thanks @lit! 
I had to install xz for windows and cygwin, and add the cygwin/bin folder to PATH in my environment variables to make it work, but eventually, it did!

Comment: There are pre-built binaries at http://tukaani.org/xz/ for Windows. You did not need to install Cygwin.

Comment: Also, Cygwin `xz` is nowhere near as fast as native `xz`.